# Is it correct to talk about "exquisite fever" when referring to fever that occurs at regular time intervals?

Tags: terminology, fever

I found this expression "fièvre exquise" in a French book.

Later, I found in a [French dictionary](https://www.littre.org/definition/exquis) that fièvre exquise is a medical term meaning: "fever, the fits of which are perfectly regular." (*fièvre dont les accès sont parfaitement réguliers*.)

I wonder if there's an equivalent term in English?

Is it correct to talk about "exquisite fever" in English when referring to fever that occurs at regular time intervals?

In English, I found the term in this text *["An epitome of the American eclectic practice of medicine, surgery, obstetrics, diseases of women and children, materia medica and pharmacy : with glossary, designed for physicians, the student of medicine, and as a domestic practice for families"](https://archive.org/stream/anepitomeameric00paingoog/anepitomeameric00paingoog_djvu.txt)*:

> (...) and  while  the  capillaries  of  the  one  are  very  much
> affected, though  those  of  the  others  are  less  so,  they  are
> by  no means  in  the  healthy  state.  In  all  cases  of  severe
> and **exquisite  fever**,  whether  intermittent,  remittent,  or  continued, the  capillaries  of  the  brain (...)

Thanks!

Comment: Context of the usage might be helpful, there are various named intermittent fevers.